# texture displacement messed up with extrusion

Tags: uv, displacement, 3d-printing

I'm 3d-printing a hedge maze and I'd like to print a hedge texture. I've made the hedges by copying and pasting a base rectangular prism and then extruding the end face to make the hedges longer. I'm then using the method I found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-tnO8jA5Lg to make a grass texture displaced: I started by subdividing and then displacing. This photo shows my problem -- the non-extruded part has a strange stretched texture while the extruded part looks fine. I've tried first applying a scale and then doing a UV unwrap before the subdivision and displacement, but this hasn't helped. I'm new to blender, so I'm likely missing something very obvious! Thanks in advance for your help! [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from an in-person blender expert who told me the better way to do this sort of thing with texture displacement is to use an array modifier instead of extruding. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem!